# Decrypt SecureString from Powershell with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, encryption

I have following Powershell-Code to encrypt my password

`$my_secure_password = convertto-securestring "myPW" -asplaintext -force
 $my_encrypted_string = convertfrom-securestring $my_secure_password -key(1..16)`

The Output is something like this
76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AHMASgB1AFMARwBxAFMAYgA1AFIAYwAyAE4AOABqAHMAOQBaADgAbwBGAEEAPQA9AHwANwBk................

How can I decrypt this output in C# in order to use it as a SecureString in C#?

I've tested something like this but this didn't work for me

```
var runSpace_new = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runSpace_new.Open();

PowerShell PSinstance = PowerShell.Create();
PSinstance.AddScript("$decrypt = convertto-securestring -key (1..16) -string 76492d1116743f0423413b.......");
var psOutput_new = PSinstance.Invoke();
var a = runSpace_new.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.GetValue("decrypt");
```

But a is null....

**UPDATE**
I have found a solution for this:

```
SecureString new_sec_pass = new SecureString();
PowerShell instance = PowerShell.Create();

instance.AddScript("convertto-securestring -key (1..16) -string 76492d1...");

foreach (PSObject psOutput in instance.Invoke())
{
    new_sec_pass = psOutput.BaseObject as SecureString;
}

PSCredential new_credentials = new PSCredential(Username, new_sec_pass);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this (maybe it help for you - for me - it is work):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

     static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var variable = PowerShell.Create().AddScript("$xtr = convertto-securestring -key (1..16) -string" + 
            " '76492d1116743f0423413b16050a5345MgB8AEQAbQBIAEIASQB6ADcAeQA0AH" + 
            "UAaAB6AFEAawBJAEYAVAA0AHcAUwBoAGcAPQA9AHwAMQAzAGUANwBmADIAOAAxADEANwAwAGUAZQBjADMANwBlAG" +
            "QAYQAxADcAZABlADEAMQBhAGYAZgBiADkAOQBiADIAMAAwAGMAMgA1AGEAZgAxADcAMABhADAAYwBjAGIAMQBhADAAZAAwADMAMwAzADMAOQAwADcAYQAzAGMANwA='" + 
            ";$PwdPointer = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($xtr);"+
            "$PlainTextPassword = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($PwdPointer);$PlainTextPassword").AddCommand("out-string");
        Collection<PSObject> results = variable.Invoke();

            foreach (var str in results)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(str);
                Console.ReadKey();

            }
        }
```

Comment: When I do this str is = System.Security.SecureString But how can I use this then in var credentials = new PSCredential(Username, new_sec_pass); ?

Comment: Ok. Can you do this? : foreach (var str in results)
            `{

                Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(str));
                Console.ReadKey();

            }`

Comment: My Script looks like this: `instance.AddScript("$decryptedpw = convertto-securestring -key (1..16) -string 76492d1.....; $decryptedpw").AddCommand("out-string");
var psOutput = instance.Invoke();

                    foreach (var result in psOutput)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(result);
                        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(result));` Both same Output: System.Security.SecureString

Comment: Yes. Sorry. =). You can convert it. I edit my answer. If you run this code - it will converting you security string to unsecurity password

Comment: Thank you. Look for the update in my first post, I have found another solution.

Comment: You're the man. This helped me.